# What is "path_to_stub_class" as identified for ParparVM?

Tags: codenameone

In your documentation for ParparVM your command line includes the following path item:

```
path_to_stub_class
```

Is this a class that is created by the application developer, or is this a class provided by Codename One?

If this is provided by the developer, where can we find the documentation/interface definition for the class?

If this is provided by Codename One, where can we find the classfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stub class is a class our server generates to run the application, it's just a class with a `public static void main(String[] argv)` method.

We call it a stub in Codename One as it hides the OS differences and calls into the lifecycle methods of the Codename One class.